# Call theme action from InsertPHP Plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, session

I am trying to set up some custom api hooks to implement a session system on our wordpress site but I am running into a few issues.

The main one seems to be that my do_action calls are not working.  Here is how I have them set up.

At the top of our Jupiter theme function.php:

```
//Custom action for PHP session handling
add_action('init', 'start_session');
add_action('glogout','end_session');


//Start custom functions for PHP Sessions
function start_session() {
        if(!session_id()) {
                session_start();
        }
}

function end_session() {
        session_destroy();
}
```

And then here is the snippet I am using in the InsertPHP (aka PHP Snippets) plugin.  This is just a test snippet, it does not make logical sense as I am deleting the session and then creating a new one; I just want to confirm that the action call is working:

```
do_action('glotout');
session_start();

if (session_id()){
        echo $_SESSION['Username']."!  Please choose a planet below to get started!";
      } else{
        echo "space cadet!  It seems as though you have not logged in.  Please return to the <a href=\"https://www.learninglabtechnologies.com/grant-login-page\">login page</a> and try again!";
      }
```

Now, the issue is that on the page I am calling the snippet from, it is not deleting the session and so I am getting a "cannot start session, one already exists" error:

> Notice: A session had already been started - ignoring session_start()
>   in
>   /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/insert-php/includes/shortcodes.php(66)
>   : eval()'d code on line 2

I am also seeing an issue with attempting to access a session variable I have set on login as per this notice:

> Notice: Undefined index: Username in
>   /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/insert-php/includes/shortcodes.php(66)
>   : eval()'d code on line 5

I am setting the Username session variable when the user logs in during the database query function which may be part of the issue.  Here is what that code looks like:

```
if ($uLoginStmt = $sql->Prepare("Select ID from Accounts where Username = ? and Password = ?;")){
        if ($uLoginStmt->bind_param('ss',$uname,MD5($pword))){
            if ($uLoginStmt->execute()){
                $uLoginStmt->bind_result($uid);
                $uLoginStmt->fetch();

                if ($uid != 0){
                    $bCompleted = true;
                    $error = "Success";

                    $_SESSION['Username'] = $uname;
                    $_SESSION['UserID'] = $uid;
                }
                ...
```

I have only used php sessions once before and not in WordPress so I am not sure if I have everything set up correctly/completely.

---

Update:

Fixed the do_action issue.  It was just a typo.  The other issue remains; I am still not able to access the session variable as described.  I probably have something set up wrong.

---

Update 2:
A var dump of the $_SESSION global from in the InsertPHP snippet resulted in this output (I removed the session_destroy call):

> array(0) { }

Answer (score 0):

Okay I got it finally.  I needed to call session_start() from within my login php functions in order to pull the session properly and set the values.  I probably also had an issue with the php configuration on our EC2 server as well as the session save path was not set and a few other options were disabled.